# Excel VBA Unfiltering macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to design a macro that will simply turn off the filtering on a certain workbook. I have begun to write the code but for some reason on the first line under the comment it causes an Application or Object defined error. I am really confused why this is happening.  I have posted the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub crossUpdate()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng1Row As Range, rng2Row As Range, Key As Range, match As Integer

Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2.xlsm").Activate

'Unhide and Unfilter columns and rows on original sheet
With Sheets("Development Priority List").Cells
 .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
 .EntireRow.Hidden = False
 .AutoFilter
End With
```

Comment: get rid of the ActiveWorkbook part.  Once you activate that workbook, just using the sheet reference should be fine.  If you'd like to keep using the ActiveWorkbook, you're going to have to explicitly state the sheet name.  Like ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Whatever That Sheet Name Is").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

Comment: It still gives me the object defined error. I made the changes to the code above.

Comment: This code works for me so it may be something else. Is your workbook/sheet/cells protected in any way?  Also where is your code stored - it should be in a 'standard' module rather than a 'sheet' module.  Perhaps also try saving/closing/reopening your workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and amend the code lines following similarly:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

To save yourself some typing you could also consider:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells
.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
.EntireRow.Hidden = False
.AutoFilter
End With
```

Comment: You will need to identify which column and which row

Comment: Why would I need to do that? I want to unhide and unfilter all of them.

Comment: Yes, apols. For some reason I was thinking about hiding (not unhiding).

Answer (score 0):

```
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End With
```